# No notification about chat response

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications

I do not seem to get a notification when someone responds to me in a chat (which has been moved from the comments section). I believe the recipient doesn't receive a notification either, as in the past, I've had to prompt them in a comment that I have responded to the chat.

Is this a bug? Is there meant to be a notification?

Answer (score 1):

If someone only posts a message in chat, you don't get a notification. You get a notification only if someone pings you (i.e. includes `@TheCodesee` in the message).

Comment: Is there a reason for this, as users who don't know this (like me for example) will not ping the recipient. Would SO consider changing this?

Comment: @TheCodesee I don't think it needs changing, because for example when I join a chatroom with lots of people, I wouldn't like to get a notification about every single message.

Comment: Maybe it would be an idea to only change it for chats between two people (e.g those moved from the comments section)?

Comment: @TheCodesee If you think it would be useful, you can post a feature request.

Comment: Yes - that would be useful. How would one post a feature request, or is there already one available I can vote on?

Comment: @ColinMackay You can post a question here, on Meta, with the [feature-request] tag.